# Translation displace imageview

Tags: android, android-animation, translate-animation

Here is my code to translate imageview in X direction(from left to right).

```
final Animation animTrans = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 1f, 0f, 0f);
        animTrans.setRepeatCount(0);
        animTrans.setDuration(200);
        animTrans.setFillAfter(true);
        circleImage.startAnimation(animTrans);
```

When it starts to translate the image is displaced in y axis. Here is a picture of what happpens.[image]

But when i use an xml to translate everything works fine. What is the problem with my code ?

Xml:

```
<translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="80%p"
        android:duration="200"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand why, but

```
circleImage.animate().
                translationXBy(width).
                setDuration(200).
                start();
```

solved my problem. I think maybe its a problem with `final Animation animTrans = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 1f, 0f, 0f);`. Those xdelta, ydelta values may be the reason.